# MediaElementjs breaking inconsistently in diff. browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement, mediaelement.js

I'm getting very inconsistant incorrect behavior between FF and Webkit, so I'm having a real hard time tracking down what the root of the problem is. The only media I am using in MP3.

In FF, MEJS is definitely kicking in at some level, and inserting most of the base container elements into the dom, but it's not rendering any control elements (play, volume, etc), but also not throwing an error.

In Chrome the controls are being rendered, but clicking play isn't playing anything, and the volume control isn't actually active (i.e. can't drag the handle).

I'm at a loss of what could be causing such different behavior with aspects of the library that should be pretty browser agnostic. Would really appreciate it if anyone has any ideas.
For the record, I have used MEJS in the past without any issues.